# Cannot applied to Operands of Type 'IEnumerable<DateTime>' and `DateTime` ( >= & <=)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following linq expression i was trying to convert string to Date and make a comparison as shown below but it gives the this error

[image]

Here is my Linq expression looks like

```
var ProjectList =  Context.Project.AsNoTracking()                                                   
                     .Include(ca => ca.Cost)                                                    
                     .Where(p => p.Cost.Select(ca => DateTime.ParseExact(ca.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) <= request.ToDate && DateTime.ParseExact(ca.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) >= request.FromDate)                                                    
                     .ToListAsync();
```

I have the `[MonthYYYYMM]` in a database as a char type

```
 [MonthYYYYMM] [char](8) NOT NULL,
```

How can i convert string to date and make the comparison?

Comment: `.Select(...)` *converts* the incoming list (of Costs) to another list. Use a `.Where(...)` to *filter*. Or maybe a `.Any(...)` or `.All(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            var ProjectList = Context.Project.AsNoTracking()
                 .Include(ca => ca.Cost)
                 .Where(p => p.Cost.Select(ca => (DateTime.ParseExact(ca.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                 <= request.ToDate) && (DateTime.ParseExact(ca.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) >= request.FromDate))                                                    
                 .ToListAsync();
```

() parenthesis around the expression you want to evaluate/compare.

Comment: Hard to see what's going on without the rest of your code, it can't evaluate a list of bool vs a bool, where is IEnumerable<bool>?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
p.Cost.Select(ca => DateTime.ParseExact(ca.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

`Select()` return `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.That's main reason of error.

```
var ProjectList =  Context.Project.AsNoTracking()                                                   
                     .Include(ca => ca.Cost)                                                    
                     .Where(ca => DateTime.ParseExact(ca.Cost.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= request.ToDate && DateTime.ParseExact(ca.Cost.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= request.FromDate)                                                    
                     .ToListAsync();
```

UPDATE

---

```
public class Cost
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public char[] MonthYYYYMM { get; set; }

        public int projectId { get; set; }


        public DateTime getDate() {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(this.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

    }



var ProjectList = Context.Project.AsNoTracking()
                     .Include(ca => ca.Cost)
                     .Where(
                            p => p.Cost.Any(c => c.getDate() <= ToDate && c.getDate() >= FromDate)
                      ).ToListAsync();
```

It works.

Comment: Thank you. that doesn't work for me i get `Cannot convert '...Entity.Cost to 'String'`

Answer (score 0):

my friend. Here is a sample. Hope to help :))

```
class Project
    {
        public List<Cost> Costs { get; set; }
    }

    class Cost
    {
        public string MonthYYYYMM { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }


var data = new List<Project>()
                {
                    new Project()
                    {
                        Costs = new List<Cost>()
                        {
                            new Cost(){ MonthYYYYMM = "202007", Price = 10},
                            new Cost(){ MonthYYYYMM = "202008" , Price = 20},
                            new Cost(){ MonthYYYYMM = "202009" , Price = 30},
                            new Cost(){ MonthYYYYMM = "202010" , Price = 40}
                        }
                    }
                };
                var fromDate = DateTime.Now;
                var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
                var projectList = data.Select(t=> new Project()
                {
                    Costs = t.Costs.Where(c=> 
                        DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= fromDate
                        && DateTime.ParseExact(c.MonthYYYYMM, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= endDate) .ToList()
                });
```